# problem with using replace-regexp in lisp

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

in my file, I have many instances of ID="XXX", and I want to replace the first one with ID="0", the second one with ID="1", and so on.

When I use regexp-replace interactively, I use `ID="[^"]*"` as the search string, and `ID="\#"` as the replacement string, and all is well.

now I want to bind this to a key, so I tried to do it in lisp, like so:

```
(replace-regexp "ID=\"[^\"]*\"" "ID=\"\\#\"")
```

but when I try to evaluate it, I get a 'selecting deleted buffer' error. It's probably something to do with escape characters, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `\#` construct is only available in the interactive call to `replace-regexp`.  From the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Replacing-Match.html#Replacing-Match):

```
In interactive calls, the replacement text may contain `\,'
followed by a Lisp expression used as part of the replacement
text.  Inside of that expression, `\&' is a string denoting the
whole match, `\N' a partial match, `\#&' and `\#N' the respective
numeric values from `string-to-number', and `\#' itself for
`replace-count', the number of replacements occurred so far.
```

And at the end of the documentation you'll see this hint:

```
This function is usually the wrong thing to use in a Lisp program.
What you probably want is a loop like this:
  (while (re-search-forward REGEXP nil t)
    (replace-match TO-STRING nil nil))
which will run faster and will not set the mark or print anything.
```

Which then leads us to this bit of elisp:

```
(save-excursion
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (let ((count 0))
    (while (re-search-forward "ID=\"[^\"]*\"" nil t)
      (replace-match (format "ID=\"%s\"" (setq count (1+ count)))))))
```

You could also use a keyboard [macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Macros.html#Macros), but I prefer the lisp solution.

Comment: If you don't mind using the `cl` package, you could use the `incf` function to bump the count -- which is just sugar to generate the `setq` call you have there.

Comment: @seh, Yah, I thought of that.  But I usually forget the `(require 'cl)` and someone points it out...